# Hiding Overflow with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a menu that slides in from offscreen. There's no horizontal scrollbar showing, but you can still slide the screen manually (in IE and Chrome, not Firefox) and see the offscreen div in the horizontal overflow. Obviously, I really want it hidden.

A simple example (without the javascript to make the offscreen div slide in) can be seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7g0x96hs/) and below:

```
<div id="maintext">I'd like the footer to display below, but the offscreen div to the left to not be visible by scrolling.</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
<div id="offscreen"></div>

body{
overflow-x:hidden;    
}

#footer{
position:absolute;
top:1000px;
width:100%;
height:10px;
background-color:#000000;           
}

#offscreen{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
z-index:1200;
background-color:#000000;
right:-100%;
top:0; 
}
```

How can I ensure the user cannot manually move the page horizontally? `overflow-x:hidden` on the body (or a wrapper div) doesn't work... Seems to be the vertical scroll that's causing the problem.

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle. the posted code isnt enough to suggest a solution. is there any other css effecting it? is the `overflow` property being overridden somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved creating a div wrapper inside of your body and applying `overflow-x:hidden;` to it.

[Check this working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3fto3kdv/4/) (try to scroll it).

```
.wrapper {
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```